# How to Pass a String to HTTPoison cacerts ssl Option

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In an Elixir Phoenix project, I am trying to connect to elasticsearch through this runtime.exs configuration:

```
config :core, Tools.ElasticsearchCluster,
  url: System.get_env("ELASTIC_HOST"),
  username: System.get_env("ELASTIC_USERNAME"),
  password: System.get_env("ELASTIC_PASSWORD"),
  ca_cert: System.get_env("ELASTIC_CERT"),
  default_options: [
    hackney: [
    ssl_options:
      [cacertfile: "ca.crt" ]
   ]
  ]
```

This works. But since the environment is not always the same and it is rather cumbersome and dangerous to provide the ca.crt file, I would like to pass the ca.crt through a string in an environment variable. I have tried to use the cacerts option, but I am stuck at transforming the pem-encoded string to a der one as specified in the Erlang SSL documentation. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, given `cacert` is the PEM-encoded CA certificate:

```
# The CA certificate is provided as a PEM-encoded string.
# Need to convert it to DER.
pem_entries = :public_key.pem_decode(cacert)
cacerts = for {:Certificate, cert, :not_encrypted} <- pem_entries, do: cert
```

You can then set `ssl_options` to `[cacerts: cacerts]`.